# What are these bugs? [Image included]

Tags: entomology

Around August I started discovering these small critters throughout my apartment. They're around 0.5-1mm long, black with six legs and two stubby antennae. I keep my glasses on the floor by my bed when I sleep and every morning, they're are 5-8 of them crawling over my glasses. The same thing happens with my hat. A number of them have died on the window sill. What are they and what are the best ways of getting rid of them? (More pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu6Bf.jpg)

Thanks!

[image: Zoomed]

Comment: I hope you have som pictures, it will be very hard otherwise!

Comment: I've attached one!

Comment: Good! Even though it's really hard to see. Looks like a beetle, at least. Strange that they are attracted to your glasses... Could you also add where you are located?

Comment: I'm guessing the glasses attraction is because of dried sweat on the bridge (my hat also has collected sweat over the years, though they favor one particular spot). I added a link to more images -- sorry they aren't high quality, the bugs are so small it's hard to get a good pic!  I'm in Chicago.

Comment: one of the picture you're linking to is a lot better than the others, maybe crop that and and add it here? anyway, i'm no expert, but some googling got me these that look kind of similar: http://puredefensepestsolutions.net/pest-solutions/pest-identifier/pantry-pests/merchant-grain-beetle/ but they (and other beetles like flour beetles) would probably prefer your kitchen. hmm...

Comment: (i keep commenting as i think of stuff) Do you have any food in your apartment? In that case I recommend that you go check that, in case they are breeding in your flour or something.

Comment: I appreciate all your comments and help! The merchant grain beetle does look like the ones I've seen. Most of my food out is dried (ie, pasta, unopened crackers). I haven't seen many bugs in the kitchen though I will be doing a thorough cleaning tonight!

Comment: It is one of the pantry pests and most likely a grain beetle. Check all dried foods in your cupboards. You cannot get rid of them until you locate the source